# System of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Common form of system of linear equations is A*X = B, X is unknown. But how to find A, if X and B are known?

A is MxN matrix, X is column vector(N), B is column vector(M)

Comment: If $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf b$ are vectors, your problem is underdetermined.

Comment: I have system of equations, such as B1 = A*X1....Bn = A*Xn

Comment: Then you can treat your set of column vectors as the columns of a matrix. mpiktas's approach then applies.

Comment: @J. M.: ...provided that $n=N$.

Comment: @Hans, Hmm, I missed that "non-square" condition... in which case, we're back to having an underdetermined problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all matrices are square, then $A=BX^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

Do it row by row. Row $k$ in $A$ multiplied by the column vector $X$ equals the $k$th entry in the vector $B$. This is a single equation for the $N$ entries in that row of $A$ (so unless $X$ is zero, you get an $(N-1)$-parameter set of solutions for each row).